# Verse Package: unwanted vertical space between lines

Tags: verse

This is an issue that's been bothering me for a while. I'm interested in typesetting poetry on narrow pages. I'm using the `verse` package to set the poem and the `geometry` package to manage the page size. When the length of a line of text just reaches the margin, a vertical space is inserted below the line.

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=5in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
% Works how I expect:
The quick brown fox jumped over the\\
Lazy dog.

% Make first line a bit longer, and now there is extra space between lines
The quick brown FOX jumped over The\\
Lazy dog.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. +1 for a well-formed MWE!

Answer (score 7):

As @tohecz has noticed that you have an overfull `\hbox`. This means that the line is longer than one line but TeX didn't find a suitable place to break the line and rather let the word stick into the margin.

Making the line yet a bit longer will show you why this produces »extra vertical space« – a new line begins, there's just nothing in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=5in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
% Works how I expect:
The quick brown fox jumped over the\\
Lazy dog.

% Make first line a bit longer, and now there is extra space between lines
The quick brown FOX jumped over The\\
Lazy dog.

The quick brown FOX jumped over the the\\
Lazy dog.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have no possibility of re-wording or changing the width of the document or the fontsize of the verse here is a compromise solution:

```
\begin{verse}
  The quick brown FOX jumped over \rlap{The}\\
  Lazy dog.
\end{verse}
```

`\rlap{}` let's its argument overlap to the right without having a width.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your line is longer than it should be, as it is indicated in the log:

```
Overfull \hbox (3.10588pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--12
```

Moreover, it is verified by the black square if you use `\documentclass[draft]{article}`

Of course, in case that your document has flaws, LaTeX won't behave predictably.

Comment: »flaw« is a bit a strong word here: an overfull hbox for good reason is not an error but a warning and there actually *are* cases where the least bad alternative is to accept a little overfull hbox. A verse might actually be a good example for this: line breaks often are given by the verse structure and re-wording is out of the question.

Comment: Well, the standard thing to do is to put the word on the next line with double indent. I more think that `verse` should set its contents `\raggedright`; it doesn't make sense to right-justify them. This as well seems to be the typographical tradition, cf. for instance the Book of Psalms in most printed Bibles.

Comment: I don't argue that in almost all cases overfull boxes can be avoided. But there are rare occasions when alternatives should be considered and poems *can* (don't have to) be such exceptions... :)

Answer (score 0):

As yo' suggested in a comment, adding a `\raggedright` declaration solved the issue for me. I'm really not sure why this isn't the default within a verse environment in the first place.